# python encoding issue - utf8 encoding not working

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have a csv file like this

```
Niklas Fagerstr�m   http://www.vimeo.com/niklasf    5379549 5379549
Niklas Fagerstr�m   http://fagerstrom.eu/en 5379549 5379549
```

I reading

```
Niklas Fagerstr�m   
Niklas Fagerstr�m
```

This two fields so all the ? characters should be encoded but my script is not encoding

```
import csv
import MySQLdb
import re
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

with open('finland_5000_rows.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        #row[0] = row[0].encode('')
        one = row[0]
        print one
```

Output:

```
Niklas Fagerstr�m
Niklas Fagerstr�m
```

But i want output like this

```
Niklas Fagerström
Niklas Fagerström
```

What change should i make in above code to get expected result?

Comment: I see a question mark initially, for the first lines of Niklas etc. When you open the csv, does the question mark show up already? What happens when you open the csv in notepad for example?

Comment: i am in linux i opened in gedit it shows like this Niklas Fagerstr�m

Comment: Not 100%, but that seems to suggest that the file encoding has issues to begin with.

Comment: what to do in this case?

Comment: How is the file generated? Namely, how did you get Niklas Fagerström? When the csv has Niklas Fagerstr�m

Comment: my friend encoded Niklas Fagerström in java i need it in python

Comment: Use latin-1 and don't abuse  defaultencoding

Answer (score 0):

What I do when this happens is, copy the text from the csv into notepad++ and press convert to UTF-8 and save it.